# Properness of the map $\psi$ in the proof of Normal bundle is a manifold

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, differential-topology

In Guillemin and Pollack's Differential Topology book while proving that the Normal bundle is a manifold they used the following argument:
Given a manifold $Y$ embedded in $\mathbb{R}^M$ choose locally an open set $\tilde{U}$ of $\mathbb{R}^M$ and a submersion $\phi: \tilde{U} \to \mathbb{R}^k$ such that $U = Y \cap \tilde{U} = \phi^{-1}(0)$. Then $N(U)=N(Y)\cap U\times \mathbb{R}^M$, is open is $N(Y)$.
Now they took the map $\psi: U\times \mathbb{R}^k \to N(U), \psi(y,v)=(y,d\phi_y^tv)$ and claimed this to be an embedding from $U\times \mathbb{R}^k \to U \times \mathbb{R}^M$. In their context embedding is a proper, injective, immersion.
I am unable to prove that the map is proper. I tried with sequential approach but could not proceed.
Any help in this regard will be appreciated.

In this regard I found the following solution by Leandro Caniglia (https://math.stackexchange.com/users/269050/leandro-caniglia), Normal bundle of a submanifold is again a manifold, URL (version: 2022-04-30): https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4439740

In this case I also want to prove that the projection onto the first coordinate from $\sigma: N(Y)\to Y$ is a submersion. For that purpose I just chose coordinates for $\tilde{U},U$ using the slice chart as in the above solution. Similarly I get a coordinate chart for $N(U)$. Then the map $\sigma$ commutes with the charts to give the canonical submersion and hence is itself a submersion.
Is this method correct?

Although this is a different approach to solve the main problem. I will still like to know the answer of my first question which I am not able to solve so far.

Comment: I haven't thought about this approach, because I usually just argued that $\psi$ is a diffeomorphism. Look at its inverse and see that it's smooth.

Comment: I tried that but I am stuck in proving that the inverse is smooth. Can you help me in proving that.

Comment: The inverse map becomes $f:N(U) \to U\times \mathbb{R}^k, f(y,u)=(y,d\phi_y^t^{-1}u)$. I was trying to prove that each component function is smooth. But not getting any apparent local smooth extension of this function. The problem I am facing is that here the domain of the linear part is also varying, otherwise I could use the virtue of smoothness of transpose and inverse. Please help me in proving this fact.

Comment: No, what you've written doesn't make sense, as $d\phi_y$ is a very non-square matrix. But try writing (without loss of generality) $d\phi_y = [B(y)|C(y)]$, where $B$ is a nonsingular $k\times k$ matrix.

Answer (score 1):

I shall not show the fact that $\psi$ is proper, but rather directly prove that the inverse is smooth following @Ted Shifrin's hint in the comments. Given $y\in Y$ we may choose the open set $\tilde{U}$ (containing $y$) in $\mathbb{R}^{M}$ to be small enough such that $\text{d}\phi_{z} = \begin{pmatrix}B(z)\mid C(z)\end{pmatrix}$ where $B(z)$ is a non-singular $k\times k$ matrix for all $z\in\tilde{U}$ (possibly by permitting coordinates). Then one may check that $\psi^{-1}: N(U)\rightarrow U\times\mathbb{R}^{k}$ is given by $$\psi^{-1}(z, w) = (z, (B(z)^{t})^{-1}\pi_{k}(w))$$ where $\pi_{k}: \mathbb{R}^{M}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{k}$ is the projection onto the first $k$ coordinates. It is easy to see that $\psi^{-1}$ is smooth since it is the restriction of a smooth function defined on $\tilde{U}\times\mathbb{R}^{M}$.